# multiplication of variables in integrals?

Tags: calculus, integration

I am just getting started with integrals(anti derivative) and my brain is still stuck with the mindset of derivatives... like product rule, quotient rule, power rule etc.

i see that integrals have power rule but no product or quotient rule, which made me confuse with relatively simple problems, take for example this problem:

$\int3x^2(x^3+7)^3dx$

i searched for some answers and got
answers like:
 you can get the answer using u substitution
and therefore the answer is:

$$\frac{(x^3+7)^4}{4} $$

i noticed that this is just saying like $\int u^3 du$(where $u = x^3+7$)
WHERE did the $3x^2$ part go?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how $u$-substitution works for your example.

Let $u = x^3 + 7$. Then $du (=\frac{du}{dx}) = 3x^2 dx$. Therefore,
$$ \int 3x^2 (x^3 + 7)^3 dx = \int u^3 du = \frac{u^4}{4}.$$
Now just substitute $u = x^3 + 7$.

Do you see what I did? To answer your question, the $3x^2$ is part of $du$.

Answer (score 1):

If $u=x^3+7$, then $du=3x^2\,dx$, and so the $3x^2$ combined with the $dx$ to give $du$.

Note: generally if $u=f(x)$, then $du=f'(x)\, dx$.  You have to take into account this part of the substitution, or you get bad results.

Further note: $u$-substitution is the rule of integration that corresponds to (reverses) the chain rule for differentiation.